# Pandas data frame with frequencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I plan building a histogram with.

The data frame contains the following values.

```
   starttime hour  
1  7/01/2015    0 
2  7/01/2015    0   
3  7/01/2015    3  
4  7/01/2015    3 
5  7/01/2015    12
```

I want to have the resulting data frame.

```
   starttime hour     frequency
1  7/01/2015    0             2
2  7/01/2015    3             2
3  7/01/2015    12            1
```

**What I have done so far**

```
df_values = Df[['starttime','hour']]
values = df_values.groupby(['starttime'])
grouped = values.aggregate(np.sum)
```

**Output I'm getting**

```
                                                        hour
starttime                                                   
6/01/2015  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
6/02/2015  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
6/03/2015  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...
6/04/2015                                                NaN
6/05/2015                                             435211
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['starttime', 'hour']).size().reset_index(name='freq')`, probable duplicate.

Comment: pandas also has a `.hist()` function if you want to plot a histogram. I think you need to first `import matplotlib` and then it's something like `df['hour'].hist()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby` + `size`/`count` -

```
c = df.columns.tolist() # c = ['starttime', 'hour']
df.groupby(c).size().reset_index(name='frequency')
```

Or,

```
df.groupby(c).hour.count().reset_index(name='frequency')
```

```
   starttime  hour  frequency
0  7/01/2015     0          2
1  7/01/2015     3          2
2  7/01/2015    12          1
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['freq'] = 1
df.groupby(['starttime','hour', as_index=False]).count()`

Comment: Your answer does not work. Did you at least run this before posting it?

Comment: you are right, thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ! I never considered there was no extra column to count or apply another aggregation function, seemed super straight forward! Updating now.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Nice, keeping it minimum! no need to get workedup (:

Comment: I was just pointing out your initial mistake, that is called "providing feedback", not getting worked up. Enjoy the upvote ;)

Comment: I appreciate it! Made me learn about grouping by all columns of a dataframe. Hey, I need the upvote man! I'm only at 1K, its a long way to get to 65K